# how to write html on image using gd library php?

Tags: php, gd, graphic

im using IMAGETTFTEXT function in php for writing text on some images.now i want to write html tags on my image,for example IMG tag.
i dont know how to do that!i want help plz.
here is my code :

```
$font_file = 'times.ttf';
$font_size=15;          
$image_file= 'new.jpg'; 

$image =  imagecreatefromjpeg($image_file);

$font_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);

imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, 55, 30, $font_color, $font_file, "fhfghfghfghfg ");
imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, 600, 30, $font_color, $font_file, "aaaaaaa ");

Header("Content-type: image/jpg");

imagejpeg($image);

imagedestroy($image);
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'write html tags on my image'? Do you want the literal text '<img src='image.jpg'/>' to be displayed? (I'm guessing not). Please be more precise in your question.

Comment: no,i want to add a image on my picture,or style my text on the image

Comment: sorry,i didnt know.how can i do that?

Comment: The green checkmark next to each answer...

Comment: FOllow the link below, worked for me!!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267846/how-to-add-text-to-an-image-with-php-gd-library

Answer (score 0):

There is no actual way to do this unless you write some kind of regular expression that replaces hyperlinks etc and creates an image from them.

Try using regular expressions and extracting useful data from the tags.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use GD to created your `<img>` sources or `<div>` backgrounds and then output the HTML separately atop them. GD is pure pixel pumping

```
   <?php ?>
   <div style="background-image: url('/image.php')"><a href="http://example.com>a hyperlink</a></div>
```

image.php

```
   header('Content-type: image/png'); 
   $image = imagecreatetruecolor(...);
   // GD generation stuff
   imagepng($image);
```