# how to create dynamic image

Tags: php, image, dynamic, computer-science

how can i create dynamic image like:
http://cache.www.gametracker.com/server_info/88.150.182.20:27015/banner_560x95.png
or like this
http://www.speedtest.net/result/2663743193.png

in this images some of selection will change, like: Status, Players, Rank, Ping
how can i have images like this :-/ ?!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using the search function (or some sort of search engine).

Comment: Not off-topic at all. OP is listing examples, but asking how to dynamically add text to an image in PHP. Don't know where you got "search engine" from...??

Comment: @Levi Search engines (for example the quite well-known "Google") are magical places where you can type what you're looking for and it _looks that stuff up for you_. It was supposed to be a funny way of saying _"this question has been asked and answered 1000 times. Google it first and use the search function."_ Maybe I was being too subtle.

Comment: I don't disagree with your intent, but you've gotta work on your written sarcasm. oops, now this is off topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GD in PHP to open an existing image, then draw text on it at specific positions, then save the image to a cache somewhere or return it to the browser if you need it to be updated upon each request.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php

Example:
[How to add text to an image with PHP GD library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267846/how-to-add-text-to-an-image-with-php-gd-library)

Comment: but it's too hard for me, how can i get the best tutorial?