# text watermark in php

Tags: php, html, watermark

I'm currently making a page, where you can upload an image.
What I need to do know is a text watermark added when you upload an image, you should be able to insert a text, which will be displayed in watermark.

it's my php

```
$location = '/usr/local/apache/htdocs/images/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];

                if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
                    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $location)) {
                        echo 'you cant copy your file';
                        exit;
                    } else {
                        echo 'you uploaded correctly<br><br>';
                        exit;
                    }
                exit;
               }
```

and thats html

```
        <input type="file" name="file" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Send" /> <br/>
        </form>
```

I looked for a while, but didn't find any tutorial which i could understand correctly

Comment: Check out the [PHP Manual for `imagettftext`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) as well as [this answer elaborating the code to write text to images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267846/how-to-add-text-to-an-image-with-php-gd-library).  If that's not simple enough for you, I've written an [old set of classes that wrap the GD functionality](https://github.com/rockerest/nox/tree/master/classes/backbone) (the pertinent classes begin with `Image`. My stuff is not well documented.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples.merged-watermark.php
im trying to use this, but I'm wondering how should I change this line
'$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('photo.jpeg');'                        

photo.jpeg to a file that I upload.

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend you to use 'Imagick' extension, with it you can use next:

```
<?php
// Open the original image
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImage("/path/to/image.jpg");

// Open the watermark
$watermark = new Imagick();
$watermark->readImage("/path/to/watermark.png");

// Overlay the watermark on the original image
$image->compositeImage($watermark, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);

// send the result to the browser
header("Content-Type: image/" . $image->getImageFormat());
echo $image;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

**text watermark in php**

```
$imagetobewatermark=imagecreatefrompng("images/muggu.png");
$font="../font/century gothic.ttf";
$fontsize="15";
$watermarktext="Muggu"; // text to be printed on image
$white = imagecolorallocate($imagetobewatermark, 255, 255, 255);
imagettftext($imagetobewatermark, $fontsize, 0, 20, 10, $white, $font, $watermarktext);
header("Content-type:image/png");
imagepng($imagetobewatermark);
imagedestroy($imagetobewatermark);
```