# PHP GD Library write text to image

Tags: php, gd

Hello following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267846/how-to-add-text-to-an-image-with-php-gd-library), i'm trying to add a text to a image using GD Library, sadly i'm unable to do it, this is my code:

```
<?php
  //Set the Content Type
  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');


  // Create Image From Existing File
  $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('serra.jpg');

  // Allocate A Color For The Text
  $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);

  // Set Path to Font File
  $font_path = 'denmark.ttf';

  // Set Text to Be Printed On Image
  $text = "This is a sunset!";

  // Print Text On Image
  imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 300, $white, $font_path, $text);

  // Send Image to Browser
  imagejpeg($jpg_image);

  // Clear Memory
  imagedestroy($jpg_image);
?>
```

**This code will Output the image without the text in it.**

The serra.jpg and denmark.ttf files are both in the same folder as the script.

Running the gd_info() function on my server i got the following:

[image: GDINFO]

Any ideas on what could possible be going on?

Comment: Does `$font_path` exist? Check that with `file_exists()`.

Comment: Yes, running  if(!file_exists($font_path)) {
       die("No font");
      }, returned nothing. So i believe the file does exist.

Comment: What are the dimensions for `serra.jpg`? Are you sure the coordinates for the text isn't out of the image?

Comment: serra.jpg is 2272x1704, i did played with the position of the text, to see if that was the problem, but no lucky there.

Comment: @André Did you check this [imagetext](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php)

Comment: @nmrony wow, by adding putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.')); i just have to add this, before the font path.

Comment: Hey,Andre.I just make some change its running.

Answer (score 1):

Go through the following steps:

- if you are working in Unix-based OS check permissions for
  `'denmark.ttf'` file. Make sure that it accessible by your php script
- change font path as follows: `$font_path = './denmark.ttf';`

Answer (score 0):

Get a solution,Check this code.

```
imagejpeg($jpg_image,'newimage.jpeg');
```

You are not save your image.

```
<?php
  //Set the Content Type
  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');


  // Create Image From Existing File
  $source="mk.jpg";
  $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);

  // Allocate A Color For The Text
  $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);

  // Set Path to Font File
  $font_path = 'ASMAN.ttf';

  // Set Text to Be Printed On Image
  $text = "This is a sunset!";

  // Print Text On Image
  imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 300, $white, $font_path, $text);

  // Send Image to Browser
  imagejpeg($jpg_image,'newimage.jpeg');

  // Clear Memory
  imagedestroy($jpg_image);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having some weird problem with the $font_path.

So reading the http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php

I saw that i have to add putenv... before the $font_path variable like this:

```
  putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));
  $font_path = 'denmark.ttf';
```

Now is working fine.

Also i tested the solution presented by Roman, and by just changing the font_path to:

```
$font_path = './denmark.ttf';
```

The script worked fine!

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: you can put your font in same folder and call it from same directory

Comment: I am notice one thing you are not generate new image you just send out put to the browser temporary

Answer (score 0):

```
$font_path = 'denmark.ttf';
```

Should be

```
$font_path = 'denmark';   //no need to incluce .ttf when not using backward slash.
```