# PHP: embed text in image when uploading it

Tags: php, image

I followed [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267846/how-to-add-text-to-an-image-with-php-gd-library) to embed text in image while uploading it but it's not working.

This is my code:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$img = $_FILES['mainImage']['name'];
list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $img);
$imgName = "ac_".time().".".$ext;
$tmp = $_FILES['mainImage']['tmp_name'];

$textToImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp);
// Allocate A Color For The Text
$white = imagecolorallocate($textToImage, 255, 255, 255);
// Set Path to Font File
$font_path = '../assets/fonts/font.ttf';
// Set Text to Be Printed On Image
$text = "Test text";
// Print Text On Image
imagettftext($textToImage, 25, 0, 75, 300, $white, $font_path, $text);

$imageUploaded = move_uploaded_file($tmp, 'images_path/'.$imgName);
if(!$imageUploaded){
    die('Error upload image!');
}
```

The image is uploaded but wihout text in it !

Comment: so is it a watermark?

Comment: do you want to do like this? http://papermashup.com/demos/php-gd-image-and-text/

Comment: @yahoo yes, I want to add a text to the image while uploading it and save it with this text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this we are working with `GD library`.

> "PHP is not limited to creating just HTML output. It can also be used
>   to create and manipulate image files in a variety of different image
>   formats, including GIF, PNG, JPEG, WBMP, and XPM. Even more
>   convenient, PHP can output image streams directly to a browser. You
>   will need to compile PHP with the [GD library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) of image functions for
>   this to work. GD and PHP may also require other libraries, depending
>   on which image formats you want to work with."

*You can use the image functions in PHP to get the size of JPEG, GIF, PNG, SWF, TIFF and JPEG2000 images.*

The following code sample demonstrates the use of GD library to watermark images on the fly. The method demonstrated here to watermark an uploaded image is to overlay the original image with another image, preferably a transparent PNG image.

PHP provides a rich set of functions to create and alter images on the fly. These functions require the GD library, which is bundled with PHP since version 4.3.

The HTML form needs a file upload element: `<input type="file">.` You must also specify the correct encoding type: `enctype="multipart/form-data"` for the form.

```
 / link to the font file no the server
$fontname = 'font/Capriola-Regular.ttf';
// controls the spacing between text
$i=30;
//JPG image quality 0-100
$quality = 85;

function create_image($user){

global $fontname;
global $quality;
$file = "covers/".md5($user[0]['name'].$user[1]['name'].$user[2]['name']).".jpg";

// if the file already exists dont create it again just serve up the original
if (!file_exists($file)) {

// define the base image that we lay our text on
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg("pass.jpg");

// setup the text colours
$color['grey'] = imagecolorallocate($im, 54, 56, 60);
$color['green'] = imagecolorallocate($im, 55, 189, 102);

// this defines the starting height for the text block
$y = imagesy($im) - $height - 365;

// loop through the array and write the text
foreach ($user as $value){
// center the text in our image - returns the x value
$x = center_text($value['name'], $value['font-size']);
imagettftext($im, $value['font-size'], 0, $x, $y+$i, $color[$value['color']], $fontname,$value['name']);
// add 32px to the line height for the next text block
$i = $i+32;

}
// create the image
imagejpeg($im, $file, $quality);

}

return $file;
}

function center_text($string, $font_size){
global $fontname;
$image_width = 800;
$dimensions = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $fontname, $string);
return ceil(($image_width - $dimensions[4]) / 2);
}

$user = array(

array(
'name'=> 'Slimen Tunis',
'font-size'=>'25',
'color'=>'black'),

array(
'name'=> 'Web developer',
'font-size'=>'16',
'color'=>'grey'),

array(
'name'=> 'SlimenTunis@webdeveloper.com',
'font-size'=>'13',
'color'=>'green'
)
);

// run the script to create the image
$filename = create_image($user);
```

here we have two functions to make it as simple as possible. To run the code simply pass the $user array data to the function and it’ll save the new image in the folder ‘covers’ on your server. The function returns the file url so you just need to echo it into an image tag as shown below. Check out the demo where you can create your own.

```
$filename = create_image($user);
<img src="<?=$filename;?>" width="800" height="600"/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is so helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [Intervention library](http://image.intervention.io/). I use it for doing what you're asking about. It is quite simple to understand and the [documentation](http://image.intervention.io/api/text) is is well-written.