# Display virtual card with dynamic content

Tags: php, html

I have a website which has a page to display member card inside the page. I also has card design (image.png) with blank content and just background color and logo inside that card design. In this case I want to add the member name and some qrcode above that card design. I get member name from database and I get the qrcode with `<img>` tag. Anyone knows how to do that and create a whole card with name and qrcode ?

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by using the PHP GD library. 
Below two links will help you to set Text on image and QR code.

To set Text on Image use  link 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267846/how-to-add-text-to-an-image-with-php-gd-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876299/merging-two-images-with-php)

After that, you need to merge two images to bind the QR code on the image.
[merge two images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876299/merging-two-images-with-php)

Comment: Okay I will try that way. Thanks