# Append text string to end of image file on page load / download

Tags: wordpress, nginx, woocommerce

I want to append something like this in real time (god help me) to a low traffic site:

When the page loads, some assets (images) are loaded (lazily)) let's assume the page would normally serve image1.png, image2.png, and image3.png

I would like to concat "username:%user%" where user is the logged in wp_user to the end of image1/2/3.png (not as a watermark, but by literally adding the string to the file itself) by real-time copying them to a temp directory and serving them from there.

While this is an unorthodox request, is there any realistic way to do this using nginx or wordpress?

Including site.conf

```
server {
server_name test.com www.test.com;
root /var/www/test.com/public_html/;
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
client_max_body_size 100M;
location / {
     proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args; 
}

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
    location = /xmlrpc.php {
      deny all;
      log_not_found off;
      return 200;
    }

listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: Don't know how your WP page is organized but generally you can do any image processing with the PHP [GD](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or [ImageMagick](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) extensions (of course you need them to be present on your server/hosting). It is also possible to do it without any temporary files generating the output on the fly.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  I have a lot of coding experience in the past but little in the way of PHP since the very early days of the internet (1998 or so).  I think that either of these should work for me as I have it self-hosted on a DigitalOcean droplet

Comment: Being self-hosted is a great advantage :) Almost every shared hosting have an option to use GD extension, ImageMagick is more powerful unfortunately often missing from hosting provider options. Anyway your task is not that complex to require ImageMagick advanced features.

Comment: I'm looking at the documentation and I see a lot of stuff that revolves around adding text to an image (visibly) but not adding it to the file itself.  Like $f = fopen("file.png","wr"); fwrite(f, $username) fclose($f) echo <img src=$f>

Comment: First result from google: [How to add text to an image with PHP GD library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267846/how-to-add-text-to-an-image-with-php-gd-library)

Comment: I think you misunderstand, I'm not trying to add text to an image, I'm trying to add text to the source of the image file, not add words on the file itself.  It's for the purpose of tracking the image.

Comment: While most software most likely would be able to read such a file, doing it that way would definitely break any image format specification. Do you want to alter only PNG images or they can be of some other format?

Comment: I would be using this exclusively on png files.  To be a bit more clear on what I'm trying to do -- if you take a look at this picture https://imgur.com/a/NQgUqAl -- download it and open it in a text editor, you will notice that I have appended the ascii string "12345678910" to the end.   png files can have an infinite amount of arbitrary text appended AT THE END of the file without disrupting the image in any way

Comment: Ok, I'd rather add this string via `iTXt` PNG chunk to not break the [format speciification](https://dev.exiv2.org/projects/exiv2/wiki/The_Metadata_in_PNG_files) however doing it just appending some data to the end of file is much more simple. How do you want to distinguish what files should be altered and what files should not? Some arbitrary list? What should happened if user is not logged in?

Comment: User cannot access the page (it's a subscription page -- this is already in place).   I basically just want to do "if file is in /uploads/master" directory, open master/1.png, append text, save output to temp folder, then just clean the temp folder on a cron or something to that effect.

Comment: So lets say all PNG files under `/uploads/master/` directory should be processed that way? Ok, I have some ideas about how this could be solved. As I already said, there is no need in temporary files. You are using nginx with php-fpm, right? It is a **very** flexible web server. Can you add your nginx config to your question?

Comment: Adding it now with redacted server names....

Comment: Main nginx file wasn't needed, you can remove it to shorten the question. Site config was needed to check what locations it contains to properly write a location for capturing requests for the PNG files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is. First, an nginx config part. If there are only PNG files inside the `wp-content/uploads/master` directory, you could use more simple

```
location ^~ /wp-content/uploads/master/ {
    rewrite ^ /pngproxy.php last;
}
```

(note the `^~` modifier, with its help this location would take priority over the `location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ { ... }` one. If there are files of other types in that directory, use the regex matching location

```
location ~ ^/wp-content/uploads/master/.+\.png$ {
    rewrite ^ /pngproxy.php last;
}
```

(should be **before** the `location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ { ... }`) This way any request for a PNG file inside the `/wp-content/uploads/master/` directory would go to the `pngproxy.php` script.

Now the PHP part. Name this file `pngproxy.php` and put it into the WordPress root:

```php
<?php
// load WordPress core
require_once('wp-load.php');

if ( is_user_logged_in() // if WordPress user is logged in
     // get an original URI from 'REQUEST_URI' FastCGI parameter and check if it is a path to .png file
     // regex can be changed to be more strict, for example including the '/wp-content/uploads/master/' path prefix
     && preg_match( '/^\\/([^?]*\\.png)(?:$|\\?)/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches )
     // and the file exists
     && file_exists( ABSPATH . $matches[1] )
     // and it is readable
     && ( $png = file_get_contents( ABSPATH . $matches[1] ) ) ) {

        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        // add user name signature
        $png .= "username:%{$current_user->user_login}%";
        // output the headers
        header( 'Content-Type: image/png' );
        header( 'Content-Length: ' . strlen( $png ) );
        // disable any sort of cache
        header( 'Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate' );
        // output the data
        echo $png;

} else {
    // generate HTTP 404 Not Found
    header( $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 404 Not Found');
    // or use HTTP 403 Forbidden if you like it more
    //header( $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 403 Forbidden');
}
?>
```